# Swift 3 - Heimdall Public key Padding

Tags: swift, rsa, padding, private-key, public-key

i am using Heimdall framework for creating and using public keys from:

https://github.com/henrinormak/Heimdall

Now i got the requirement to use 1024 bit RSA zero padding for my keys and i have absolutely no idea how to set the padding during:

```
self.heimdall = Heimdall(publicTag: tag, privateTag: tag, keySize: 1024)
```

Could anybody help out here?

Thanks and Greetings!